# User as a consumer in express-gateway

Tags: express-gateway

I am looking at express-gateway to be used in my app as API Gateway. Going through the documentation https://www.express-gateway.io/getting-started-with-oauth2/

I am a bit confused, as to, if user created here means a client or the end user.

MY Scenario:

I currently have only single client app and all the users belongs to this client app.

What I am trying to do is create an end user.

Question:

- Does API-gateway provide an endpoint which can be used to CRUD on end users?
- Does API-gateway provide an endpoint where I could query with username and password of end user as parameter and authenticate them returning a JWT? Query here means, using my client app's login form with username and password fields, which is then passed to authenticated at the gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, Express Gateway provides an [Admin API](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/admin/) which you can use to provision new users as well as removing/changing them in the way you want. Once you make sure it's properly protected, you're good to use it for your purposes.
2. Yes. The oAuth2 policy is already providing a simple login form that will ask the user to put its username and password and, if that works, it will authenticate the user and return a JWT (or an opaque token based on your configuration).

Let me know if that answer your questions or not.

Cheers,

V.